# Ajax callback is not invoked

Tags: 7, ajax

I am using Drupal 7, and I used `hook_form_alter()` to add the following markup.

```
  $form['linkb'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup'=>"<a href=''>Click here </a>",
    '#title' => t('something'),
    '#name' => 'linkb',
    '#ajax' => array(
      'method' => 'html', // this is important without this if else condition for ajax will not work.
      'effect' => 'fade',
      'callback' => 'clicktell_verification',
      'wrapper' => 'replace_textfield_div',
    ),
  );
```

I want to run AJAX when I click on *Click here*, but this is not working. I have also created a callback function, but it doesn't still work.

Why isn't the AJAX callback being called?

Answer (score 2):

[#ajax](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax) is never used by elements of [markup](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#markup) type. You need to use it with one of the following elements:

- button
- checkbox
- checkboxes
- image button
- password
- radio
- radios
- select
- submit
- tableselect
- textarea
- text_format
- textfield